# Output for every single if-formula, CS50 Problem Set Credit

Tags: cs50

I'm currently doing the CS50 online course and got stuck on the second exercise credit. The objective is basically to give a credit card number (or any number really) as input and get an output as either invalid or one of the three major credit cards (Master, Visa or AmEx).

My code works almost the way I intended, in that I get the correct output, my problem ist that its in the wrong format.

If I input a non-credit card number instead of

INVALID

my output looks like this:

INVALID
INVALID
INVALID
INVALID
INVALID

if I give an AmEx credit card number as input my output looks like this:

INVALID
AmEx
INVALID
INVALID
INVALID

This is my code:

```
int main(void)

{
long long CreditCardNo;

do
{
    CreditCardNo = get_long_long("Enter credit card number:");
}
while (CreditCardNo <= 0);


int countDigits = 0;
long long count = CreditCardNo;


//run loop until number is no longer an integer

while (count != 0)
    {
        //Incremental counter

        countDigits++;

        //Divide input number by 10 to reduce one digit from integer

        count = count / 10;
    }

//return "Invalid" for all numbers with any amount of digits other than 13, 15 & 16

if (countDigits != 13 && countDigits != 15 && countDigits != 16)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }



//Take 2nd to last digit, and then the every other digit, and multiply by 2 to get the first part for the checksum
int digit1  =   (((CreditCardNo / 10) % 10) * 2);
int digit2  =   (((CreditCardNo / 1000) % 10) * 2);
int digit3  =   (((CreditCardNo / 100000) % 10) * 2);
int digit4  =   (((CreditCardNo / 10000000) % 10) * 2);
int digit5  =   (((CreditCardNo / 1000000000) % 10) * 2);
int digit6  =   (((CreditCardNo / 100000000000) % 10) * 2);
int digit7  =   (((CreditCardNo / 10000000000000) % 10) * 2);
int digit8  =   (((CreditCardNo / 1000000000000000) % 10) * 2);

//Take last digit and then every other to get the second part for the checksum
int digit9  =   (CreditCardNo % 10);
int digit10 =   ((CreditCardNo % 1000) / 100);
int digit11 =   ((CreditCardNo % 100000) / 10000);
int digit12 =   ((CreditCardNo % 10000000) / 1000000);
int digit13 =   ((CreditCardNo % 1000000000) / 100000000);
int digit14 =   ((CreditCardNo % 100000000000) / 10000000000);
int digit15 =   ((CreditCardNo % 10000000000000) / 1000000000000);
int digit16 =   ((CreditCardNo % 1000000000000000) / 100000000000000);

//Add all digits for first checksum
int check1  =   digit1 + digit2 + digit3 + digit4 + digit5 + digit6 + digit7 + digit8;

//Add all digits for second checksum
int check2 = digit9 + digit10 + digit11 + digit12 + digit13 + digit14 + digit15 + digit16;

//Add checksums

int check3 = check1 + check2;

//If checksum doesn't end in 0 return invalid


if (check3 % 10 != 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }



//Validation for AmEx

int CheckAmex = CreditCardNo / 10000000000000;

if (CheckAmex != 34 && CheckAmex != 37)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
else
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }



//Validation for MasterCard

int CheckMasterCard = CreditCardNo / 100000000000000;

if (CheckMasterCard != 51 && CheckMasterCard != 52 && CheckMasterCard != 53 && CheckMasterCard != 54 && CheckMasterCard != 55)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
else
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }


//Validation for Visa

int CheckVisa1 = CreditCardNo / 1000000000000;

if (CheckVisa1 != 4)
    {
         printf("INVALID\n");
    }
else
    {
        printf("Visa\n");
    }


int CheckVisa2 = CreditCardNo / 1000000000000000;

    if (CheckVisa1 != 4)
    {
         printf("INVALID\n");
    }
else
    {
        printf("Visa\n");
    }
}
```

I've tried repackaging the very first if formula into an else and layering the others into this first one but I can't seem to get it to work, as I end up getting new errors along the lines of "undeclared identifier 'CheckMasterCard'" (or Visa or really anything else).

Is there a simple solution I'm missing and can implement easily, or do I need to rework the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the program checked for the previous `if` statements and prints "invalid" in every invalid case until it reaches a statement to execute. For example, the "AMEX" it prints "invalid" for visa, master card and the check you did.